# show the Firstname of the picked UserID in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops

I have form that select User ID among Users.

```
<select>
    <option value="">Tabs User</option>
      <option value="ID3357">ID3357</option>
            <option value="ID2695">ID2695</option>
            <option value="ID1072">ID1072</option>
            <option value="ID1306">ID1306</option>
            <option value="ID2702">ID2702</option>
```

The First name of the users:
ID2695  Jacob
ID1072  Moe
ID1306  sara
ID2702  Sam

how to show the Firstname of ID below the form, when the enduser pick the ID in form.

Comment: Where in your code is Jacob? Are you really hardcoding all the values/ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code might help,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="name"></h1>
    <select onchange="getUser(this.value)">
        <option disabled selected value>-</option>
        <option value="ID3357">ID3357</option>
        <option value="ID2695">ID2695</option>
        <option value="ID1072">ID1072</option>
        <option value="ID1306">ID1306</option>
        <option value="ID2702">ID2702</option> 
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var users = [
            { id: "ID2695", firstName: "Jacob" },
            { id: "ID1072", firstName: "Moe" },
            { id: "ID1306", firstName: "Sara" },
            { id: "ID2702", firstName: "Sam" },
            { id: "ID3357", firstName: "Someone" }
        ];
        function getUser(uid) {
            var [{ firstName }] = users.filter(({id}) => id === uid);
            document.getElementById("name").textContent = firstName;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation: The users are hard-coded into the js as objects with and id and username. As soon as somebody picks a value from the dropdown, js gets the value from the dropdown input and filters the array + selects the `firstName` from the returned array of an object. Then it displays that into the h1. As simple as that.

Comment: Greeeeaat, appreciated